# For given seminorm $p$ on a linear space $X$. Show that map $[x] \$

Tags: functional-analysis

For given seminorm $p$ on a linear space $X$. Show that map $[x] \longrightarrow p(x)$ is a norm on the quotient space $X/p^{-1}(\{0\})$.

Let's call this map $d$. We have to show three statements:

$1.$ $d([x]) = 0 \iff [x] = [0] \in X/p^{-1}(\{0\})$.

$d([x]) = 0 = p(x)$ hence we receive $x \in p^{-1}(\{0\})$ which by the definition of class of abstraction $[x] = [0]$. But in fact $[0]$ is a zero in quotient space.

Statements second and third are the result of properties of seminorm which are basically the same as for the norm.

$2.$ $d([cx]) = d(c[x]) = p(c\cdot x) = |c|\cdot p(x)$

and

$3.$ $d([x+y]) = p(x+y) \le p(x) + p(y) = d([x]) + d([y])$.

Is is correct so far? Moreover, in this task there is a question in which particular situation we create normed space from seminormed space?

Comment: Perhaps most importantly, show that it is independent of the representant $x$ you choose, ie the map is well defined.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I mean seriously how do we examine such thing?

Comment: @janusz $[x]$ is a set / equivalent class. It is a singleton if and only if $p$ is already a norm.